# how to subscribe to a observable in our .ts file from authguard.ts

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, redux-observable, auth-guard

I have implemented an authguard service in which consist of following void service method.

```
loadOrganizations() {
    console.log("loading organizattions")
    this.getOrganizations().subscribe(
      (results) => {
        const organizationList = [];
        if (results.organizations) {
          results.organizations.forEach((element) => {
            this.appendOrganization(element, organizationList);
            this.loadChildrenOrganization(element.children, organizationList);
          });
        }
        this.organizations$.next(organizationList);
        this.organizations$.complete();
      },
      (error) => {
        this.organizations$.next([]);
        this.organizations$.complete();
      }
    );
  }
```

my auth guard service as follows.

```
canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
     this.appService.loadOrganizations();
     console.log("authuard is calling")
     return true;
  }
```

How can I subscribe to a observable in which we get data(from authguard) of organization in another ts file.(within ngOnit??)

Comment: you can pass your required data into a parameter by adding new one parameter to `loadOrganizations` function

Comment: May i ask, why are u using `AuthGuard`, it is not suppose to be use in this way

Comment: the reason I have used the service call is to load the data before page is initiating. And need to load this loaded data to the component that i'm using

Comment: you may need to use Resolver  instead of Auth Guard to achieve desired results

Comment: can we call this subscription in my ngOnit function? any way or clue to do this?